# Omnet++ IDE keeps freezing when starting own project

Tags: ide, omnet++, workspace

when I start my own project in the workspace folder:

```
/home/schmidtd/workspace
```

the IDE immediately is freezing and I can't use it aynmore. I'm working on Ubuntu and its just getting gray after I start my project.

BUT!!

if I start the  IDE with the preinstalled workspace folder:

```
/home/schmidtd/omnetpp-4.6/samples
```

it works perfectly. Does anyone had the same problem or has a solution for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the `.metadata` folder in your workspace folder would reset its state. So you may be able to get it to a working state.